# How can I see the exact value for inputs and outputs for a convolutional layer in MobileNet

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to visualize the inputs and outputs for a convolutional layer in MobileNet. Is there any function or tools in TensorFlow that allow us to see the exact value for inputs, outputs for each layer?
So let's say if I have an image, I am doing object detection. The model run through a bunch of layers, how do I see the data flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [the TensorFlow debugger, tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger). You can inspect intermediate activations, including gradients.

Enabling [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) is another option, where TensorFlow will behave more like numpy than a domain-specific language. You can print intermediate activations using regular print statements, or use Python's pdb.

A third option is to add [`tf.Print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) nodes to the graph. Similarly you could [add summaries and send them to TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard).